# Zabbix Content Monitoring XPath or Regex

Tags: zabbix

We are using Zabbix 2.4 and I need to monitor the content on a URL. I do not have control of the URL, but the output is in an HTML table and so doing a string match it not going to cut it. Can Zabbix match on content using Regex or XPath? This would make what I am trying to do a million times easier.

I have looked at [Zabbix Macros](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/appendix/macros/supported_by_location), but nothing there seems to do what I need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Zabbix does not support XPath. You have two options with regexps:

1. You can use the built-in [web monitoring](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/web_monitoring), and match with a regexp in the `Required string` field (note that [global regexps](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/regular_expressions#global_regular_expressions) are not supported here).
2. You can use [Zabbix agent item](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent) `web.page.regexp` and match a regexp right there. Or you could use `web.page.get` item, then match with `regexp()` or `iregexp()` [trigger function](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/appendix/triggers/functions). Note that this [does not work as expected with chunked transfer encoding](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-9892).